# Open and close app at location with Shortcuts

Tags: macos, shortcut, shortcuts-app

I've been getting tired of having to open certain apps and switch network profiles when coming into the office and home.

It's not a huge annoyance, more a lazy person's inconvenience.

But I was wondering if there was a way of configuring the system based on location?

I was thinking of using Shortcuts, but if there was something better I'm open to it.

My thinking was:

1. Get the current location
2. Check if the location is within 10 meters my contact profile work location addess
3. If true:

   1. Switch Network Location to "Work" profile
   2. Open work proxy app
4. If false:

   1. Switch Network location to "Home" profile
   2. Quite work proxy app

This was for macOS and not my iPad or iPhone - if possible.

I tried looking for some of those options in the Shortcut app but couldn't find anything for switching locations or getting my contact profile addresses and narrowing it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no GPS in Mac so the idea of getting the location within a radius is not possible. (There are commercial options to get the Wifi location e.g. Skyhooks) but for your simple use case, I suggest you create an `Apple Script` that automate certain tasks.

Here is a direction you can use to continue building your own script.

Open `Script Editor` Utility from `Applications/Utilities`

Paste the following code and run it. (It opens iTunes and Quits Activity Monitor or can be used to quit any other app that is installed.

```
tell application "iTunes" to activate

tell application "Activity Monitor"
    quit
end tell
```

You can Run the script with the play button on the script editor. When you are done, you can export your script as an `Application`. More details can be found here.

How to write [Apple Script](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/CreateaScript.html)

Here are few links to [Switch Network](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250075360) from Apple Script.

Comment: This looks better suited to be a comment rather than an answer given that it includes too few details and suggested actions. You should also "quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline" according to the "[How do I write a good answer?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) Ask Different support webpage.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I often use the mobile app and it’s not very convenient to compose a well written answer.